# How to upload large files to Google Cloud Storage with GAE/SE go112

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I can use Blobstore API (blobstore.UploadURL) with GAE/SE go111, but it was abolished in GAE/SE go112.
How do I upload large files to GCS?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to migrate to the Google Cloud client library to access GCS. https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage